# MFC MDI Menu Bar Icon MainFrame vs Loaded Added Menu Icon->How to control/Edit?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2017, icons, menuitem, mdi

When my `MDI` app opens and loads `m_wndMenuBar` and waiting for the user to open a file to begin file operations, in the `MenuBar` it has the `menuitems` like File, View, ....etc.

When the user loads in a file, the app switches from `IDR_MAINFRAME` to `IDR_TRAINS` and the `menuitems` are updated.....but somehow, somewhere, a magic icon shows up which is the main icon I use for the program itself.

I want to add the icon to the `IDR_MAINFRAME` but can't figure out how or where to add it. I see `mainframe.ico` in the `.rc` file but not seeing a correlation of the two menus as to why one would have it but the other not.

Any ideas on how to add the icon to the `IDR_MAINFRAME` as I like the icon there.

[image: IDR_MAINFRAME][image: IDR_TRAINS]

Comment: When you maximize an MDI (child) window frame the icon associated with the document type is added to the left of the menu-bar, this is normal. The application's title contains the application icon (IDR_MAINFRAME), which may is not the same as the one(s) associated with the document type(s).

Comment: Is there a way to perma add it as a placeholder regardless of the child? It isn't annoying persay, just wondering if I can keep the "menu flow" consistent as it keeps showing up and disappearing as you mention between maximized or other.

Comment: And what are you going to put there, if there is no document open? The application one? You are going to have it shown twice then, as in your pic, which looks weird. And there's no much benefit either, as the "menu flow" isn't consistent at all, as there is one menu per document-type, in addition to the IDR_MAINFRAME one (shown when there is no open document and lacking an "Edit" column). These are more or less consistent across desktop applications, and everything else would rather look somehow non-standard imo.

Comment: Surely you should keep this kind of thing as "expected" GUI behaviour?

Comment: Also, I think it is down to the GUI style you chose. For me, my documents show as horizontal tabs so I don't have the same issue as you.